# Mocking a function that has a try/catch to force an error for Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, try-catch, ts-jest

We have some jest tests setup for a Typescript/Express API. The basic `GET` route returns some data.

```
itemsRouter.get('/', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const items: Item[] = await ItemService.findAll();

    res.status(200).send(items);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e.message);
  }
});
```

We are trying to mock the catch block of this route. Which is only called if an error is thrown with the try/catch.

How can we mock throwing an error within the route? Or should we try to mock the service `findAll` instead and throw there somehow?

The service is only an example so its fairly simple just returning some data currently:

```
export const findAll = async (): Promise<Item[]> => Object.values(items);
```

Comment: "*Or should we try to mock the service findAll instead and throw there somehow?*" there is no other way to go to the `catch` except if `findAll` throws, so - yes, you have to force that somehow. In general if you somehow make the `try` fail, that doesn't give you a guarantee that it works the same as `findAll` throwing.

Comment: Sure, so the question is how should we mock/spy to make the try fail.

Comment: [`.mockRejectedValue()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrejectedvaluevalue)

Answer (score 0):

I will use [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) to write tests for your case. We can use `jest.mock()` to mock `ItemService` module, and use [.mockRejectedValueOnce()](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrejectedvalueoncevalue) method to mock a rejected value for `ItemService.findAll()` method.

E.g.

`app.ts`:

```
import express from 'express';
import type { Request, Response } from 'express';
import type { Item } from './ItemService';
import * as ItemService from './ItemService';

const app = express();

app.get('/', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const items: Item[] = await ItemService.findAll();

    res.status(200).send(items);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e.message);
  }
});

export { app };
```

`ItemService.ts`:

```
export interface Item {}

const items = { a: '1', b: '2' };

export const findAll = async (): Promise<Item[]> => Object.values(items);
```

`app.test.ts`:

```
import { app } from './app';
import request from 'supertest';
import * as ItemService from './ItemService';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';

jest.mock('./ItemService');

const mItemService = mocked(ItemService);

describe('66582815', () => {
  it('should get status code 500 and an error message', (done) => {
    const mError = new Error('network');
    mItemService.findAll.mockRejectedValueOnce(mError);
    request(app)
      .get('/')
      .expect(500)
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) return done(err);
        expect(res.text).toBe('network');
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66582815/app.test.ts
  66582815
    ✓ should get status code 500 and an error message (16 ms)

----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File            | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files       |      80 |      100 |      50 |   90.91 |                   
 ItemService.ts |      60 |      100 |       0 |     100 |                   
 app.ts         |      90 |      100 |     100 |   88.89 | 12                
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.073 s
```